# How do I get the YouTube video ID from GDataEntryYouTubeVideo?

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-upload, youtube, gdata

I'm using the GData/YouTube direct upload api. When the upload is finish the following method gets called:

```
- (void)uploadTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
  finishedWithEntry:(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)videoEntry
           error:(NSError *)error {
```

How can I get the YouTube video ID of the just uploaded video from the returned (GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)videoEntry?

Comment: Did you check the `identifier` & `resourceID` properties?

Comment: No, I'll give those a try. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Not completely sure, but those seem (by name) to be the properties you could need.

Comment: resourceID is null but identifier is something like tag:youtube.com,2008:video:xhdOBV9jlks Any idea how to get the value of "video" without having to split the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this worked for me:

```
NSString * videoID = videoEntry.mediaGroup.videoID;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the URL from

```
[[[[videoEntry mediaGroup] mediaContents] objectAtIndex:0] URLString];
```

This comes with some query string cruft, but the base URL is the video (once the processing's been completed).